# how to display custom post type in archive.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created custom post type with general categories (for default posts and custom posts the same categories) through the Custom Post Type UI plugin.

How to make on the category page so that, in addition to defaulted posts, custom posts for the same category are also displayed? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function like this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( (is_category() or is_archive() ) && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'your_post_type' ) );

    return $query;
}
```